# Data Import, primery key choice and Active Record best practices

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, import, primary-key

I have read several times that using 'custom primery key' (other than the id of the object) in Active Record was not a good practice and that it must be used very carefully.

Here is my problem:

I am building a Rails App. I'll have to import objects such as `:products`, `:countries`, `:regions`, etc... in my database.

I am planning to do it by CSV imports. Sometimes, I'll probably reset a table and re-import it entirely with more data. Using codes instead of ids as `primary_key` would have been really convenient, it would have ensured my database is still consistent after reimporting the data. I'll just need  to make sure date always keep the same `code`every time I import it (which will be easier than trying to keep the same `id`).

1. What are the danger of using 'codes' as primary keys?
2. Are there 'intelligent' ways to manage CSV import so that objects
   always keep the same id?
3. What is the best practice in my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to override the `primary_key` as it can break some of the Rails magic. Also you will have to write monkey patches to make it work. I would recommend creating a new column called `code` and index it. This way, your code will always be the same regardless of how many times you import.

You will have to use `Region.find_by_code(code)` or `Region.find_by_code!(code)` to do your queries. The bang method(method with the '!') will raise an exception if the record not found, analogous to `Region.find(id)`.